# python pandas read_excel(filename) but i found '~$' before the real filename

Tags: python, pandas

code:

```
df_512g = pd.read_excel(resource_file, sheet_name=0, header=None,names=header_name, skiprows=6, usecols=encols_512g)
```

and printout is:

> debug:  C:\Users\Datalog\~$ID byte.xlsx
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found

Comment: Are you able to open the file otherwise? Is the file also open in `Excel` or any other program at the same time?

Comment: Files preceded by `~$` are temporary files created when you work with documents in the Office suite. Those are so-called 'lock files' or 'owner files'. Normally, these files are deleted automatically when you save/close the file but might hang around if Excel crashed. I know this doesn't answer your question but it may shed some light on the `~$` files.

Comment: but in my function test, it can be open and i got data from it.

Comment: @Mortz in function test, can open it. And the file is in the folder, if some file is unclosed, will it course the problem?

Comment: @Alinluga I think that caused this problem

Comment: as a test: See if you can save the file without the `~$ID` so like `C:\Users\Datalog\byte.xlsx` and open it again with `pd.read_excel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i forgot when i open the excel file and didn't save it correctly, so left a temporary file which occurs in python console with ~$ before the real file name.

Solution is create a new folder and add new file into it. It works.